# Golang regex to extract values inside parantheses and ignore inner parantheses in any

Tags: regex, go, re2

I have the following example of *key=value* pairs as one line string

> `start=("a", "b") and between=("range(2019, max, to=\"le\")") and end=("a", "b")`

Using regex in golang I want to extract the key=value pairs as below

1. `start=("a", "b")`
2. `between=("range(2019, max, to=\"le\")")`
3. `end=("a", "b")`

There are solutions on stackoverflow but do not work with golang regex.

There is a link to my failed attempt with golang regex: [regex101 golang flavor](https://regex101.com/r/YccNOj/1)

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: `strings.Split(x, " and ")`

Comment: For the given example your solution works, but I might not work for a value like _start=("a", " b and a")_.

Comment: don t use regexp for that. Write a parser, it is super easy.

Comment: A quick [unrolled](http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop) idea: [`\w+=\([^)(]*(?:\([^)(]*\)[^)(]*)*\)`](https://regex101.com/r/Fs8nTw/1/) But if it comes to arbitrary nested parenthesis and no regex recursion is available, a parser is the only solution. If it's about the escaped quote, you can also try something like [`\w+=\(".*?[^\\]"\)`](https://regex101.com/r/Fs8nTw/2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the escaped quotes:

```
\S+=(\([^(]*(?:[^("]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\["\\])*")(\)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/3ytO9P/1

I changed `[^"]` to `(?:[^\\"]|\\["\\])`. This makes the regex look for either a regular character or an escape. By matching the escape, it doesn’t allow `\"` to end the match.

Your regex has other problems though. This should work better:

```
\S+=(\([^("]*(?:[^("]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\["\\])*")*(\)))
```

https://regex101.com/r/OuDvyX/1

It changes `[^(]` to `[^("]` to prevent `"` from being matched unless it’s part of a complete string.

---

**UPDATE:**

**[@Wiktor Stribiżew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3832970/wiktor-stribi%C5%BCew)** commented [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59323720/3150271#comment104849549_59323720):

> It still does not support other escape sequences. The first `[^("]*` is redundant in the current pattern. It won't match `between=("a",,,)` but will match `between=("a",,",")` - this is inconsistent. The right regex will match valid double quoted string literals separated with commas and any amount of whitespace between them. The `\S+=(\([^(]*(?:[^("]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\["\\])*")(\)))` is not the right pattern IMHO

If you really want the regex to be that robust, you should use a parser, but you could fix those problems by using:

```
\S+=(\((?:[^("]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\.)*"[^("]*)*(\)))
```

Comment: You must explain the regex a bit. It's too complicated IMO

Comment: But it won't match `between=("range(2019, max, to=\"le\")", "b")`, see https://regex101.com/r/3ytO9P/2. `\S+=(\([^(]*(?:[^("]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\["\\])*")(\)))` is a wrong pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. I didn’t see that in the original regex. Updated.

Comment: Thanks @Anonymous works perfectly :)

Comment: @M.H.Hussaini You’re welcome :)

Comment: It still does not support other escape sequences. The first `[^("]*` is redundant in the current pattern. It won't match `between=("a",,,)` but will match `between=("a",,",")` - this is inconsistent. The right regex will match valid double quoted string literals separated with commas and any amount of whitespace between them. The `\S+=(\([^(]*(?:[^("]*"(?:[^\\"]|\\["\\])*")(\)))` is not the right pattern IMHO

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew There are definitely other changes you could make. It’s not clear from the question that these are what the OP wants though, but it’s good to point them out